# Angular mat-badge doesn't work well for dynamic data

Tags: angular, badge

I need three chips on one single line. the numbers that re displayed in the chip are coming from a json object. I've tried using both material badges and chips. For badges, I can display the data, but the badge behaves weirdly when my number is bigger than 6 digits. For chips, I cannot figure out how to bind the data. Here is my code for the badges

ts file

```
  getTotalBatches(jobs: Job[]): number {
    return jobs.reduce((acc, job) => acc + job.batchCount, 0)
  }
```

html file

```
<p>
      <span [matBadge]="getTotalBatches(jobs)" matBadgeOverlap="true" matBadgeColor="warn" matBadgePosition="below after"><span
        class="badgeText1">Batches</span></span>

      <span [matBadge]="getTotalReports(jobs)" matBadgeOverlap="true" matBadgeColor="warn" matBadgePosition="below after"><span
        class="badgeText">Reports</span></span>
      <span [matBadge]="getTotalRecords(jobs)" matBadgeOverlap="true" matBadgeColor="warn" matBadgePosition="below after"><span
        class="badgeText"> Records</span></span>
    </p>
```

scss file

```
.mat-badge-content {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 30px;
  min-height: 30px;
  display: grid;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;

}

.badgeText {
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-left: 35px;

}

.badgeText1 {
  padding-right: 40px;

}

.mat-badge-medium.mat-badge-below .mat-badge-content {
  top: 20px;
}
```

I have tried many things to bind chips, but nothing works and there's nothing online that is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Change the matBadge as Input prop

```
<mat-icon [matBadge]="badgeContent">
```

notifications

```
export class BadgeComponent implements OnInit {

  badgeContent : number;
  constructor() {
    this.badgeContent = 10;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

This will allow to pass notificationItemNumber as input property from component

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using chips. I was able to inject the data, I was doing it the wrong way. Here is my code for the chips. Each chip contains an icon that contains my data(numbers)

```
html file
<div>
      <div class="md-chips">
        <div class="md-chip">
          <div class="md-chip-icon"> {{getTotalBatches(jobs)| number}}</div>
          Batches
           </div>
        <div class="md-chip">
            <div class="md-chip-icon"> {{getTotalReports(jobs) | number }}</div>
            Reports:
         </div>
          <div class="md-chip">
            <div class="md-chip-icon"> {{getTotalRecords(jobs) | number }}</div>
            Records:
          </div>
```

css file

```
$md-chip-height: 32px;
$md-chip-color: #e0e0e0;

.md-chip {
  display: inline-block;
  background: $md-chip-color;
  padding: 0 12px;
  border-radius: 32px;
  font-size: 13px;
  &.md-chip-hover:hover {
    background: #ccc;
  }
}


.md-chip, .md-chip-icon {
  height: $md-chip-height;
  line-height: $md-chip-height;
}

.md-chip-icon {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background: #e60028;
  width: $md-chip-height;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 8px 0 -12px;

}

.md-chips {
  padding: 12px 0;
  .md-chip {
    margin: 0 5px 3px 0;
  }
}
```